# JavaScript - select all text inside a ‘pre code block’ on double-click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code block on my blog; I want that when someone double-click on a code block, all code of that code block need to be selected.

Please look at the code below (this is what I’ve got so far, though it is using **jQuery**). Now **is it do-able with native JavaScript( without jQuery )** ?

*Sorry If I've asked a dumb question, I’m new at these things. :)*

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<style>
pre.highlight {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // select all code on doubleclick
    $('pre.highlight').dblclick(function() {
        $(this).select();

        var text = this,
            range, selection;

        if (document.body.createTextRange) {
            range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(text);
            range.select();
        } else if (window.getSelection) {
            selection = window.getSelection();
            range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(text);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
    });
});
</script>
<pre class="highlight"><code>.button-css {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    background: #F2861D;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    margin: 7px 0 0;
    color: #f4f4f4;
}</code></pre>
<pre class="highlight"><code> #slider {
     border-color: #c0c0c0;
     border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
     border-style: solid;
 }</code></pre>
```

Comment: Can you add sample HTML as well. A jsFiddle would be useful

Comment: do you want to get it with native javascript?

Comment: You might find some useful code in [my greasemonkey script](https://github.com/calraith/gm_scripts/blob/master/se_like_I_like_it.user.js).  Full details at my [stackapps post](http://stackapps.com/q/5038/29449).

Comment: Yes I want to achive that with native JavaScript @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works fine in *Jquery*. 
To get the "native javascript" version go through the following steps:

- replace jquery's `$(document).ready` handler with native
  `window.onload`
- work with event target `e.target` instead of jquery's `this`
- instead of adding an event handler for each element with
  `class="highlight"` use advanced technic which is adding the event
  listener to the parent element once and considering only needed `pre` or
  `code` elements (related to `class="highlight"`)

  ```
  window.onload = function(){

      document.body.addEventListener('dblclick', function(e){
         var target = e.target || e.srcElement;        
         if (target.className.indexOf("highlight") !== -1 || target.parentNode.className.indexOf("highlight") !== -1){
              var range, selection;

              if (document.body.createTextRange) {
                  range = document.body.createTextRange();
                  range.moveToElementText(target);
                  range.select();
              } else if (window.getSelection) {
                  selection = window.getSelection();
                  range = document.createRange();
                  range.selectNodeContents(target);
                  selection.removeAllRanges();
                  selection.addRange(range);
              }
              e.stopPropagation();
         }              

      });
  };
  ```

https://jsfiddle.net/8nba46x8/

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for the explanation.  @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 1):

Converting jQuery to JavaScript for your code is easy, you did the hard part already.

> var srcBox = document.querySelector(".sourceBox");
>
> srcBox.addEventListener("dblclick", hiLite, false);

- Wrap the content in another container (`.sourceBox`) because the most efficient way to handle multiple event listeners is to place the one event listener on the parent of all of the `event.target`s (the element where the event originated from, or simply the element that was actually clicked).

> if (e.target !== e.currentTarget)

- Even though the `event.target` would be one of the `pre` elements but the listener is on the parent, we can still find the correct `pre` element by checking if it's **not** the `event.currentTarget` (`.sourceBox`) in the event chain as it probigates (and stops short of `event.currentTarget`) and bubbles (and stops short of `event.currentTarget`). The normal event chain is stopped short because of the `false` parameter of the event listener and the `e.stopPropagation();` placed at the very end of the function hiLite (event handler)

> var text = e.target;

- Singling out the correct `event.target` allows us to use `this` more or less. I believe that `this` in this context is still `.sourceBox` which in this situation is useless, which is why we're using `event.target`

As you can see this is one of the many reasons why many prefer jQuery over JavaScript. I'm a masochist so naturally I prefer JavaScript.

Now that my incoherent ramblings have thoroughly confused you, here's **[an article](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)** that explains it better than I can.

```js
var srcBox = document.querySelector(".sourceBox");

srcBox.addEventListener("dblclick", hiLite, false);

function hiLite(e) {
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
    var text = e.target;
    var range, selection;

    if (document.body.createTextRange) {
      range = document.body.createTextRange();
      range.moveToElementText(text);
      range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
      selection = window.getSelection();
      range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNodeContents(text);
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);
    }
  }
   e.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
  pre.highlight {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .sourceBox {
    border: 2px inset #222;
    padding: 1px 15px;
  }
```

```html
<section class="sourceBox">
  <pre class="highlight"><code>.button-css {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    background: #F2861D;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    margin: 7px 0 0;
    color: #f4f4f4;
}</code></pre>
  <pre class="highlight"><code> #slider {
     border-color: #c0c0c0;
     border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
     border-style: solid;
 }</code></pre>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you @zer00ne. Thanks for your kind explanation.

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad that you understood me, despite my bad writing skills.:)

Answer (score 1):

For pre or any tag one can select all text inside that tag by this simple code. It will highlight the entire tag area with yellow colour and select text inside it on single click.

```
document.onclick = function(event) {
    var range, selection;
event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        selection = window.getSelection();
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(event.target);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to implement the same functionality in native javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectText(containerid) {
        if (document.selection) {
            var range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
            range.select();
        } else if (window.getSelection) {
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
            window.getSelection().addRange(range);
        }
    }
</script>
```

To use the above function you can write in HTML like this :

```
<div id="selectable" ondblclick="selectText('selectable')">This is a test div.</div>
```