# How to select the text in verbatimTextOutput by default in Shiny?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

This is a related question to my previous question ([Is it possible to have fixed width verbatimTextOutput and have texts change lines in Shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58516071/7669809)). I have the following shiny app (https://yuchenw.shinyapps.io/Shiny_verbatimtext_fixed/) with a `verbatimTextOutput` that can display long texts. Is it possible to select those texts by default? An example would be the behavior of the bookmark button. As the following screenshot shows, when the bookmark pop-up window shows up, the texts have been selected already. I would like to reproduce the same behavior using `verbatimTextOutput`.

[image]

**Code**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- function(request){
  fluidPage(
    tags$style(type='text/css', '#txt_out {white-space: pre-wrap;}'),
    column(
      width = 6,
      textInput(inputId = "txt", label = "Type in some texts",
                value = paste0(rep(letters, 10), collapse = "")),
      strong("Show the texts"),
      verbatimTextOutput("txt_out"),
      br(),
      bookmarkButton()
    )
  )
}
server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$txt_out <- renderText({
    input$txt
  })
}
enableBookmarking("url")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Do you have to use `verbatimTextOutput` or is `textOutput` also an option? `verbatimTextOutput` wraps the text in a pre-tag, what makes things a little more complex.

Comment: @ismirsehregal I think `textOutput` is also an option. But I would be interested in learning how the bookmark button achieves this. It seems like the bookmark button is using `verbatimTextOutput`.

Comment: I'm currently not having a PC at hand. However, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35297919/javascript-select-all-text-inside-a-pre-code-block-on-double-click/) might point in the right direction.

Comment: I've had a short look at the text diplayed in the modal. In the source code they aren't using a `pre`-tag (like `verbatimTextOutput`) they are using a `textarea`-tag in readonly mode (`textAreaInput` or `tags$textarea` in shiny). You can find the according css for class `form-control` in the file `library/shiny/www/shared/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css`. Type `urlModal` in the R console to see the textarea definition and the according JS used or `urlModal("urlDummy")` for HTML.

Comment: @ismirsehregal Thanks for showing me the path to move forward. I will study it and see if I can come up with an answer.

Comment: That would be great, sorry it's too much work to do it by the way. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50744444/select-text-set-focus-in-textinput) you can find another interesting approach for `textInput`.

Comment: @ismirsehregal No need to say sorry. I know you may be busy and you don't have the responsibility to help me, so I appreciate all your help and suggestions. Thank you so much.

Comment: @ismirsehregal Thanks for your help. I have developed a workaround and posted it here as an answer. If you are interested in developing a solution focusing on `verbatimTextOutput` or other strategies using `textAreaInput` and if you have time to share it, you can still post here. I would be glad to accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for @ismirsehregal's help. Here I shared a workaround of this question. This answer uses `textAreaInput` in read-only mode, not `verbatimTextOutput` as I originally asked for. However, I am satisfied with the outcome and final appearance of the `textAreaInput`.

I learned how to select texts based on this post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50745110/7669809). I also learned how to set read-only mode for the `textAreaInput` from this post ([Make textarea readonly with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3297923/7669809)). Here is my code.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- function(request){
  fluidPage(
    column(
      width = 6,
      tags$head(
        tags$script("
      Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('selectText', function(message) {
        $('#txt_out').select();
        $('#txt_out').prop('readonly', true);
      });
    ")
      ),
      textInput(inputId = "txt", label = "Type in some texts",
                value = paste0(rep(letters, 10), collapse = "")),
      textAreaInput("txt_out", label = "Show the texts", heigh = "300px"),
      br(),
      bookmarkButton()
    )
  )
}
server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$txt, {
    updateTextAreaInput(session = session, inputId = "txt_out", value = input$txt)
  })
  observeEvent(input$txt_out, {
    session$sendCustomMessage("selectText", "select")
  })
}
enableBookmarking("url")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is how it looks when the app runs.

[image]